# Unknown directories /pipermail /poll accessible in Drupal 7

Tags: polls, files

My Drupal 7 install, has the Simplenews and Polls modules enabled, but Simplenews is set to subscribe registered members only, and Polls are only open to authenticated users. Yet, the mysite.com/pipermail and mysite.com/poll directories are accessible to anonymous view.

The mysite.com/poll directory returns a page with the Drupal theme only, and the word "Polls" in the page title, and no other data. The mysite.com/pipermail directory returns a blank page, absolutely no data.

These directories are not seen anywhere in the directory tree when I checked using File Manager in cPanel. This is a CentOS 5.10, php 5.4 install. How does one check Drupal's internal directory tree, especially to verify whether the permissions are correctly set on these unknown directories?

How do I remove these problematic directories? Also, is it possible that this flaw can be maliciously attacked, say by ftp upload means, etc.?

Comment: Did you check permissions in "admin/people/permissions" ?

Comment: Yes, I checked the permissions and anonymous user doesn't have access to anything in Polls.  In simplenews, I've checked the subscribe option for anonymous users, because I need the 'silent' option of subscription for simplifying sending of service messages.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is a Dynamic Content Management system unlike old style files and directories where you find path specific directory.. Various features are available from modules in Drupal... Modules implements menu paths using hook_menu...

For your case, module exposes permissions settings which you can set in "admin/people/permissions" for different roles... Login as admin and access above page to set access permissions..

[image]